# Dual boot disks not being detected and nouveau unknown chipset

Tags: drive, nouveau, fdisk

I have a Dell XPS 15 and have a dual boot setup with ubuntu 16 and windows 10. It was working fine then one day randomly ubuntu stopped loading and i started getting the error:

```
[ 2.597747] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (137000a1)
Gave up waiting for root device. Common Problems..
```

I have tried adding nouveau to the blocklist to no avail. When i load ubuntu live via a usb it doesnt detect my partitions. I have tried `sudo fdisk -l` and `testdisk` aswell. When i try viewing the partitions on my windows OS they seem to work fine.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Not really relevant, but are you booting UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow not really sure how do i check

Comment: Perhaps try to bypass the issue with the following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu then perform an update, driver check etc.

Comment: already tried, it doesnt work (iv mentioned this in my question)

Comment: If Ubuntu worked before, I don't know why this would have changed for you, but enter your BIOS and see if your disk is setup for RAID. If so, that's probably your problem. Did you do a BIOS reset to factory recently?

Comment: Are you able to default to onboard graphics and then load appropriate drivers for your GPU? (Assuming you're using a GPU)