# Ubuntu Live Cannot detect my harddisk or its partitions

Tags: partitioning, ssd, fdisk, testdisk

I have a dual boot setup of ubuntu with windows 10. I recently started having a problem that didn't let me boot into my ubuntu installation. So to figure out the problem i tried using a usb to run a live version. It cant seem to find my harddisk or any of its partitions. Iv tried using `testdisk` and `sudo fdisk -l` but noone of them detect my ssd either.

My windows 10 installation is working fine and i can even read my ubuntu partitions on it with diskinternals linux reader.

Comment: *My windows 10 installation is working fine and i can even read my ubuntu partitions on it with diskinternals linux reader* **is probably the cause of** *I recently started having a problem that didn't let me boot into my ubuntu installation*.

Comment: i only installed diskinternals linux AFTER i couldnt boot into ubuntu

Comment: If so, by using it, you're only making it worst. And I haven't noticed before you had another question. Pleasa follow up there instead of opening duplicates. In comments there is a clarification request (UEFI or Legacy) and a suggestion. Have you tried that? Results? (No, do not answer here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot disks not being detected and nouveau unknown chipset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941503/dual-boot-disks-not-being-detected-and-nouveau-unknown-chipset)

Comment: If Ubuntu worked before, I don't know why this would have changed for you, but enter your BIOS and see if your disk is setup for RAID. If so, that's probably your problem. Did you do a BIOS reset to factory recently?